# Why are the commas in my array reading as a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

This is what I am trying to do:

1 - I have an array with a string.

```
$photographer_array = "'Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams'";
```

2 - I am trying to populate an array with that string.

```
array($photographer_array);
```

What it is doing is creating an array with one single entry including all the commas. Why is it reading the commas as a string? Is there anyway I can make it not read the commas as a string and instead use them to separate the values in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to say that, but you cannot populate an array this way, since strings are usually not parsed and executed. All you can do is:

```
$photographer_array = array('Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams');
```

Or this (**EDIT**: Adapted it to your query code):

```
$photographer_array = array();

while ($photographer_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $photographer_array[] = $photographer_row['photographer_name'];
}
```

P.S.: You just love long variable names, don't you? ;)

Comment: Thank you very much Franz! That worked great! Sorry to confuse everyone. I should have showed you my query right away. Thanks for all the quick replies!

Comment: Yeah im running multiple queries on that page, so I wanted it to be obvious which one is which, therefore the long variable names. weird habit i guess

Answer (score 3):

That's because `$photographer_array` **is** a string and using `array($photographer_array)` simply puts your string to the array.

Perhaps you want to do:

```
$photographer_array = explode(',', "'Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams'");
```

This will give you

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "'Alberto Korda'"
  [1]=>
  string(18) " 'Annie Leibowitz'"
  [2]=>
  string(14) " 'Ansel Adams'"
}
```

Or you want:

```
$photographer_array = array('Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams');
// ...
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the code you posted - the following will give you an array of the `$photographer_row['photographer_name']`:

```
// ...
$photographer_array = array();
while($photographer_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $photographer_array[] = $photographer_row['photographer_name'];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I needed. Franz beat you to it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's reading the string as a string becuase you enclosed it in quotation marks ( " ). If you want to do it right, try:

`$array = array('Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams');`

Or:

`$string = "Alberto Korda, Annie Leibowitz, Ansel Adams";
 $arr = explode(',', $string);`

Answer (score 1):

you'll notice that the variable `$photographer_array` is set to a single string (the value of which is everything between the double quotes). The array function in php accepts a list of objects delimited by commas. While there are commas in your `$photographer_array` variable, they are considered to be characters in the string rather than actual delimiters, so you're really just creating an array with only one value which happens to be a string. What you probably want is  the following:

```
$photographer_array = array('Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to PHP >= 5.3.0, then you can use [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), which parses a comma-separated string into an array.

Comment: `str_getcsv()` is a PHP >= 5.3.0 function. Just to take note of this.

Answer (score 0):

`Explode()` is what you need...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: That's going to end in pain if the values themselves contain commas.

Comment: Also not the right thing for what Chris really wants, although you couldn't know that obviously...

Answer (score 0):

Im actually creating an array using values from a query just so you know why I am doing it this way. This is the code I am using to create the string for use in my array.

```
$sql = "SELECT photographers.photographer_name
        FROM photographers
        ORDER BY photographer_name ASC
        LIMIT 3";

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

$photographer_array = '';

while($photographer_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$photographer_array .= "'" . $photographer_row['photographer_name'] . "', ";
}

$photographer_array = rtrim($photographer_array, ", ");

array($photographer_array);
```

Comment: In that case just use my second approach.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. `$photographer_array` is a string, period. Why don't you push values into array instead of concatenating them into string?

Comment: Y'know, PHP is not strong-typed, but that doesn't mean it does on the fly conversion between strings that look like written out arrays and arrays.

Comment: nOrd, that's what Franz's second approach does and I have applied it now.

while($photographer_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$photographer_array[] = $photographer_row['photographer_name'];
}

Answer (score 0):

If you need a string to make a array use:

$photographer_array = "'Alberto Korda', 'Annie Leibowitz', 'Ansel Adams'";

```
eval("\$myArray = array(" . $photographer_array . ");");
```

And after use `$myArray`